# Really simple CoreData relationship but returns nil and null?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, entity-relationship, one-to-one

This bug has been busting me for the past 4 hours.

Also when I swap it round and get the User data first then Message data... the `User.name` will show, but the `Message.message` will not. So the data is definitely going in but the relationship between them seems to be broken.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, +1 for the effort with the image you created to illustrate your problem.

The cause of your issue is that you never assigned the user to the message (or vice-versa).

Try

```
message.fetchUser = user;
```

or

```
user.fetchMessage = message;
```

Then save your context and perform the fetch request.

Comment: I had to change the code a bit (messageDetails.fetchUser = userDetails), but massive thanks for showing me the way, I love u.

Answer (score 0):

As Rog said, I needed to assign the user to the message (or vice vera). Basically I placed this bit of code after where its entering the data.

```
messageDetails.fetchUser = userDetails
```